# Select all columns for each item's maximum date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table as such:

```
_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
itemID INT
price DECIMAL
priceDate DATETIME
```

Each itemID can have different prices set at different dates (so I can keep track of price changes in time)

However, I am perplexed as how to retrieve each item's current price while avoiding duplicates (that is, for each item, get all columns for each maximum date).

Some Sample Data:

```
_id itemID price pricedate
1   1   50.00   2016-06-14 00:00:00
2   2   50.00   2016-06-14 00:00:00
3   3   85.00   2016-06-14 00:00:00
4   4   95.00   2016-06-14 00:00:00
...
120 1   1000.00 2016-08-11 12:41:13
```

Expected Output:

```
_id itemID price pricedate
2   2   50.00   2016-06-14 00:00:00
3   3   85.00   2016-06-14 00:00:00
4   4   95.00   2016-06-14 00:00:00
120 1   1000.00 2016-08-11 12:41:13
```

note that itemID of 1 has two entries. Recently the price changed from 50 to 1000. I only want to display each item with their maximum pricedate

Comment: Show your expected output based on some sample data.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Luckily, this question is asked endlessly. And sometimes, it's answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. But in case more than 1 item has same `pricedate`, then the results could be ambiguous. Unfortunately `MySQL` don't have `partition by` clause so you have to either derive it or get to an alternative approach.

```
select t.* from your_table t
inner join 
(select item_id,max(pricedate) as pricedate 
    from your_table 
group by item_id
) d
on t.item_id=d.item_id and t.priceDate=d.priceDate
```

Explanation: The inner query gives you each `item_id` and `max(priceDate)` for that `itemid`. But you will not get other columns which corresponds to this row. So you would use the parent table again and join based on these two derived column. Hope it is clear.

Comment: I saw a similar answer to yours, but it didn't perfectly work for me. Yours seems to work! Thank you. If you could edit your answer with an explanation, then myself and others may be able to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. Your answer is clear. I'm others will benefit from it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select foo._id,foo.itemID,foo.price,foo.priceDate 
from foo 
inner join 
    (select itemID,max(priceDate) as tp from foo group by itemID) maxD on (foo.itemID=maxD.itemID and foo.priceDate=maxD.tp)
```

Subquery in inner join gets top dates of itemID's and filters duplicate rows.